# Api call from Ionic app not hitting on server Api

Tags: spring, ionic4

I am new to Ionic. I didn't get any solution for this from here.

This is my ionic.config.json

```json
{
  "name":"BarcodeScannerApp",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type":"angular",
  "proxies":[
    {
      "proxyUrl":"http://localhost:8085"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below  is the method in service class

```ts
public getProduct(barocode: any, basketBarcode: any): Observable<any> {
   this.url = '/api/v1/barcode/scan';
   let queryParameters = new HttpParams();
   queryParameters = queryParameters.set('barcodeInfo', barocode);
   queryParameters = queryParameters.set('basketId', basketBarcode);
   const requestOptions: any = {
     params: queryParameters
   };
   return this.httpclient.post(this.url, requestOptions);
 }
```

This gives below  error

> POST http://192.168.0.9:8100/api/v1/barcode/scan 404 (Not Found)

Server  side method is below

```java
   @RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/barcode/scan", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<ServerResponse> getProductInfo(@RequestParam("barcodeInfo") String barcodeNo, @RequestParam("basketId") String basketId) {

    return null;
    }
```

Comment: If your Server code uses Spring (Boot), you should add the associated tag, as it sounds like a server configuration issue.

Comment: server configuration works fine . I tried from post man and it hits on server

Comment: Your API url seems for local so your mobile device can access this network?

Comment: I am running the application  using livereload command. so it connects to wifi. And it always takes client side port.. where do i define my server side port other than ionic.config.json ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue . It was the CORS issue, which i was supposed to add @crossOrigin(" * ") annotation.
If the server is CORS enabled, it will parse the Access-Control-Request-* headers and understand that a request is trying to be made from http://localhost:8100 (Ionic client) with a custom Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's should be work. You should use the HTTP header like "Content-type" etc